# Code showing error of expected assignment or functional call

Tags: reactjs

The piece of code i have pasted below gives me an error showing expected an assignment or function call, I think there is a syntax error can anyone check please

```
 render() {
    const { orderDisplay } = this.state.orders;

    return (
      <div>
        {orderDisplay.map(order => {
          <Order
            key={order.id}
            ingredients={order.ingredients}
            price={order.price}
          />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: let orders = orderDisplay.map(order => {
          <Order
            key={order.id}
            ingredients={order.ingredients}
            price={order.price}
          />;
        })

Use this before return and then simple add {orders}

Answer (score 1):

This is not syntax error but linter error caused by ESLint `no-unused-expressions` rule. `map` callback is supposed to return a value, but it doesn't.

To make use of implicit return in arrow function, it should be

```
{orderDisplay.map(order => (
  <Order ... />
))}
```

instead of

```
{orderDisplay.map(order => {
  <Order ... />
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something from .map function

like this

## 1

```
render() {
    const { orderDisplay } = this.state.orders;

    return (
      <div>
        {orderDisplay.map(order => {
          return <Order
            key={order.id}
            ingredients={order.ingredients}
            price={order.price}
          />;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

or if you don't do any logic inside that function you can directly return some value

## 2

```
render() {
    const { orderDisplay } = this.state.orders;

    return (
      <div>
        {orderDisplay.map(order => (
          <Order
            key={order.id}
            ingredients={order.ingredients}
            price={order.price}
          />;
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I went with the second one.